# "Error converting asset" when building ARCore's hellosceneform example

Tags: arcore, sceneform

When I build "hellosceneform" example in Android Studio, I got an "Error converting asset" error from Gradle. Can anyone tell me how to build the example? Thanks!

Comment: The best place to get help for issues like this is the github repo for sceneform samples.  Can you create an issue there and include any error messages from gradle and the operating system and version you are using?  Thanks!  https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues

Answer (score 0):

Please update your Sceneform gradle plugin version to 1.0.1 if you have having trouble building the hellosceneform example (or get the latest samples which already incorporate this new version).

To update an existing Sceneform project with this fix, in your project build.gradle file, replace this line:

`classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.0.0'`

with this line:

`classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.0.1'`

Answer (score 0):

beside this error,there is another error,ERROR: Failed to write '/var/tmp/tmp.0.TkT65Y',because there is no directory named tmp at the path, so i create a tmp directory and give it 777 permission,this solved my problem 
:)